# Why 'Django Migrate' re-create foreign-key constraint when just adding null=True

Tags: django, postgresql

The below is `git diff` output of a `Django model.py`.

```
-    live = models.ForeignKey('live.Live', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
-                             related_name='live_likes')
+    live = models.ForeignKey('live.Live', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
+                             related_name='live_likes', null=True)
```

The only difference between them is `null=True` and I expected that Django just run SQL dropping `NOT NULL`.

However, it is the real output of `sqlmigrate` of `Django`.

```
SET CONSTRAINTS "live_like_live_id_0374bfe6_fk_live_live_id" IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE "live_like" DROP CONSTRAINT "live_like_live_id_0374bfe6_fk_live_live_id";
ALTER TABLE "live_like" ALTER COLUMN "live_id" DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "live_like" ADD CONSTRAINT "live_like_live_id_0374bfe6_fk_live_live_id" FOREIGN KEY ("live_id") REFERENCES "live_live" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Surprisingly, it does additional action re-creating foreign-key constraint the same as the previous one.

Is It normal in Django and Why?

I think this additional action could lead to tremendous fail in production server side.

(Django 2.0.5, PostgreSQL 9.6.9)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, and I believe it's a variation of https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25253 in the wild.

The tldr is to run raw sql to add your constraint, and use the  `state_operations` directive to make Django satisfied with your change so it doesn't continue to recreate the foreign key. A good example of this is https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25253#comment:15.